# How to convert text to date, then get year value?

Tags: date, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Need to convert a text value `2012-03-19' into a date type, then extract the year component.

```
<xsl:variable name="dateValue" select="2012-03-19"/>
<xsl:variable name="year" select="year-from-date(date($dateValue))"/>
```

I'm using Saxon 2.0, but it's complaining `date` function does not exist; I looked around Saxon's documentation and could not find the function, so that's clearly the issue, but I can't find a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `date()` should be a function, you want the `xs:date()` data type.

Add the `xs` namespace and then prefix `xs:date()`.

The following stylesheet, using any well-formed XML input, will produce `2012`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="dateValue" select="'2012-03-19'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="year-from-date(xs:date($dateValue))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you also have to quote your `select` in your "dateValue" `xsl:variable`.